# How do I extract members of a javascript array into individual variables available to the program?

Tags: javascript, ajax, leaflet

My Ajax call returns a `json_encode`d array object that I grab using a function from `success:` like this:

```
var poiReturn = $.parseJSON(response);
```

I extract individual array entries like this:

```
var POIMarkerList    = poiReturn[2];
```

But `POIMarkerList` looks like below and there are others at [0], [1], etc.:

```
var EOCList = L.layerGroup([W0KCN4, W0KCN3, W0KCN15, NARESEOC]);var FireList = L.layerGroup([RVRSDEFD, KCMOFS1, KCMOFS3, KCMOFS4, KCMOFS5, KCMOFS6, KCMOFS7, KCMOFS8, KCMOFS10, KCMOFS16, KCMOFS17, KCMOFS18])]);
```

As you can see this example has two var definitions (`EOCList` & `FireList`). How do I get javascript to create individual variables to make them available to the javascript program as if I had defined them like this?

```
var EOCList = L.layerGroup([W0KCN4, W0KCN3, W0KCN15, NARESEOC]);
var FireList = L.layerGroup([RVRSDEFD, KCMOFS1, KCMOFS3, KCMOFS4, KCMOFS5, KCMOFS6, KCMOFS7, KCMOFS8, KCMOFS10, KCMOFS16, KCMOFS17, KCMOFS18]);
```

Comment: Could you rephrase it better? I don't see the problem. Couldn't you just do `var EOCList = poiReturn[2][0]; var FireList = poiReturn[2][1];` ?

Comment: @sanitzedUser each of your examples only returns the the first letter of var (v). I need javascript to see the two var statements in the array individually. But obviously you are on to a solution I'm just not sure how to get there yet.

Comment: Wait, `json_encode` is building up a *string* like `var OECList=...`? I'm confused. I'd like to see the PHP code behind that.

Comment: Looks indeed like a bad separation between PHP backend and JavaScript frontend. Help for an immediate fix would need sharing the PHP code. A better solution would be to review the relative roles of backend and frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed directions on this project, and will try it another way.